# Who is this extra in Zodiac?

Tags: identify-this-actor, zodiac

It's the man who played a TV news reporter in [Zodiac (2007)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0443706/) approximately 2 hours and 10 minutes (130 minutes) into the movie. It's during family dinner scene after Robert (Jake Gyllenhaal) and his son are excused from the table to watch the news. The reporter's name is Alan Freeman (sp?). I have no clue who he is! I'm pretty sure he's uncredited, but I know for sure he's been in other things.

[image]

Comment: Couldn't see that name on the IMDB cast listing. Uncredited extra?

Comment: @Jared, yeah, the character's name isn't on the IMDB cast listing. He must be uncredited, but his face is so familiar, (I know someone has to recognize it!)

Comment: How about a screenshot? As it stands, only those who have a copy of the movie handy will be able to answer your question.

Comment: @coleopterist, I wanted to include pictures, but I don't have enough reputation yet :( I'm almost there though.

Comment: @user5726 Give us a link and we'll add it for ya :)

Comment: @user5726:  Well, whichever is easier, getting a little more reputation or uploading the photo to http://PicPaste.com or something similar.

Comment: I was trying to figure out who this person is too. The second picture above is of the reporter with curly hair that was on the television when Avery (Downey, Jr.) was in the bar. The one you are thinking of reminds me of a blonde Patrick Dempsey with a mustache. I have not been able to find any other evidence of him myself.

Comment: He looks like Scott Jacoby or Matthew Modine to me.

Answer (score 3):

[Bill Seward](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0786537/) played a news anchor in the film (uncredited) - is this who you think you saw?

[image]

Alternatively, [Mitchell Fink](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm1697724/) is uncredited but plays a reporter in the film - ring any bells?

[image]

Comment: Bill Seward is the one who introduced before the actor I'm looking for. He introduces the reporter as "Alan Freeman."

Comment: I have amended my answer to see if that floats your boat ;)

Comment: Yeah I found him in the uncredited list too, but it doesn't look like him either...and I don't recognize his face from anything else. I feel like the part was given to a well known actor, and that he chose to take the part without any credit.

Comment: Is the clip online at all? Perhaps we could ID from that.

Answer (score 3):

Pretty sure this is a cameo by LA anchor and sportscaster [Barry LeBrock](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0443706/fullcredits/).

> Barry LeBrock is an American sportscaster, based in Los Angeles, California. LeBrock is one of the primary anchors on FSN Final Score, the nightly news program seen Nationally on Fox Sports Net and most affiliates of Comcast SportsNet. LeBrock's résumé also includes anchor, hosting and investigative reporting work at Fox Sports Net West/Prime Ticket and Fox Sports Net Northwest. On February 18, 2007, he contributed to the debut of the NASCAR Hot Pass pay-per-view package on DirecTV. He was the main announcer providing dedicated coverage of NEXTEL Cup Series driver Michael Waltrip.

[He's in the credits as Reporter (Uncredited)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0443706/fullcredits/) and looks *exactly* like the person in the scene, only he has a 70s moustache there (and he does resemble Patrick Dempsey a bit):

[image]